# deploying ASP.NET web applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-4.5

I have a web application created using ASP.NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 on my local machine, which I publish to the development machine that I have access to. We have preprod/staging and production environments for this application, which I don't have access to, and the release team (which knows nothing about the application) is in charge of releasing the application to these environments. I need to provide release steps to them.

What's the best/easiest way for the release team to get the latest version of the application from the dev machine and release it to preprod and then to prod? Is it to create a web deployment package?

Since Visual Studio is not installed on dev, preprod and prod machines, one-click publish using Web deploy won't work, right? Prod server can be set up for the Web Deployment Agent Service (MSDepSvc/Remote Agent service).

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a command line version of VS one-click publish? So instead of clicking 'Publish' button in VS, one can run a command to have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to use the publish feature to publish the web app to a directory on your local machine. Change connection strings, etc, then hand off to your deployment team as a ZIP file. Make sure to also give them instructions on configuring the application pool/directory in IIS, as well.

Comment: Thanks Cam, I think so too.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same situation. The best way i could find so far is to create a WIX(Windows Installer XML) package and handover to them. It has already been successfully applied to large enterprise projects and works in a awesome way.

This will help you get started:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163456.aspx
```

This is a bit complex but once you get into this you will not like other ways.

This is opensource and has lots of resources to get started. Microsoft has removed the setup project feature from Visual Studio  2012 version and is recommending to use this. If you had done deployment or packaging and releasing before i hope you will understand the suggestion i gave you.